# Zariski Topology on Primary Spectrum $P$-$\operatorname{Spec}(R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

So there's a proposition in Hummadi's journal Primary Spectrum I'd like to ask. It is said if given $R$ principal ideal domain and $a,b \in R$, then

1. $D_p(a) \cap D_p(b) \supseteq D_p(ab)$, and
2. $D_p(a) \cap D_p(b) = D_p(ab)$  iff $\gcd(a,b)=1$

Given $$D_p(a)=\{P \text{ primary ideal}\mid a \notin P\}$$ I try to prove it by myself by thinking if $ab \notin P$ then $a \notin P$ because $P$ primary, hence $b \notin P$. But I can't help feeling that there's something missing. So, could anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

part 2 hint:

The generator of $P$ is a prime power $p^n$, and when $\gcd(a,b)=1$, $p^n|ab$ iff $p^n$ divides $a$ or $b$. When $\gcd(a,b)=m\not=1$, then WLOG let $m|a$ and $m^k|b$ and $p$ be a prime such that $p^n|m$ and $p^{n+1}\not|m$ for some $n\geq 1$. Then $ab$ is in the ideal generated by $p^{kn+1}$ which neither $a$ nor $b$ are in.

Comment: Oh thank you. So does it means that my proof on point (1) is right? Can't seem to think that way though..